# Wireless adapter Realtek [0bda:818b] problems - used to sometimes connect, now not at all

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, usb

I am unable to connect on wireless. I am using a wireless usb adapter.

Thanks to [this thread][1], I am easily able to present the following diagnostic info:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 03 Mar 2016 12:30 CET +0100

Booted last: 03 Mar 2016 12:23 CET +0100

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-62-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 14:29:36 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8554]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 045e:0780 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 05e3:0723 Genesys Logic, Inc. GL827L SD/MMC/MS Flash Card Reader
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:818b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

cfg80211              484040  0 
eeepc_wmi              13151  0 
asus_wmi               24191  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          13948  1 asus_wmi
video                  19476  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    19177  1 asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'docker0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:10.42.0.86  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8567 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6222 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8016298 (8.0 MB)  TX bytes:1343942 (1.3 MB)

lxcbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'lxcbr0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:10.0.3.1  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'lxcbr0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:97 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:14169 (14.1 KB)

vmnet1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'vmnet1' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.6.1  Bcast:192.168.6.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'vmnet1' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:97 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vmnet8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'vmnet8' [IF]>  
          inet addr:172.16.198.1  Bcast:172.16.198.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'vmnet8' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:98 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

vmnet8    no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

lxcbr0    no wireless extensions.

vmnet1    no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.42.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
172.16.198.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.6.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1022     1  0 12:23 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8192eu
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 
    MovieStarPlanet_2_4: Infra, <MAC 'MovieStarPlanet_2_4' [AN1]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 16 Mb/s, Strength 100 WPA2
    MSP:             Infra, <MAC 'MSP' [AN2]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 16 Mb/s, Strength 90 WPA2
    Copenhagen2:     Infra, <MAC 'Copenhagen2' [AN3]>, Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 16 Mb/s, Strength 60 WPA2
    Magick:          Infra, <MAC 'Magick' [AN4]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 16 Mb/s, Strength 100 WPA WPA2
    Orbit Guest:     Infra, <MAC 'Orbit Guest' [AN5]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 16 Mb/s, Strength 69 WPA2

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         10.42.0.86
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         10.42.0.1

    DNS:             10.42.0.1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Orbit Guest]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Orbit Guest | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Orbit Guest | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Magick | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Magick
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Copenhagen (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

vmnet8    no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

lxcbr0    no frequency information.

vmnet1    no frequency information.

docker0   no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

##### iwlist scan #######################

vmnet8    Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

lxcbr0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

vmnet1    Interface doesn't support scanning.

docker0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     No scan results

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-62-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     695424C2F5CD23A91B67E25
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-62-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        E0:7C:FC:BE:E8:34:59:BA:45:54:3D:39:B2:C2:A5:78:75:74:50:01
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/vmware-fuse.conf]
alias char-major-10-229 fuse

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8192eu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[  189.645025] RTL871X: rtw_scan_timeout_handler(wlan0) fw_state=808
[  347.962941] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link up
[  347.962957] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  349.032411] bridge-lxcbr0: disabling the bridge
[  349.047488] bridge-lxcbr0: down
[  349.047497] bridge-lxcbr0: detached
[  349.047585] bridge-eth0: up
[  349.047591] bridge-eth0: attached
[  349.474871] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready

########## wireless info END ############


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/17643
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Realtek RTL8192EU device.

You need to install a driver. Connect to internet by wire and run in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192eu-dkms
```